# An Unity3D button appears to be null while trying to disable it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

What I'm trying to do is disable the button when the time is up. But I get an error while I set the button to be disable: it appears to be null.

The following script (**RightButton.cs**) includes a function called DisableButton that is invoked by the main script (**TappingEngine.cs**).

The statement that hangs inside the DisableButton function is `btn.interactable = false;`.

```
/* RightButton.cs */

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RightButton : MonoBehaviour {

    Button btn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("Right button ready.");
    }

    public void Tap()
    {
        Debug.Log("Tap right! tot: " + TappingEngine.te.nTaps);
        TappingEngine.te.Tap(TappingEngine.tapType_t.right);
    }

    public void DisableButton()
    {
        btn = this.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

The following code is <s>a part of</s> the main script (which is quite long).  However, someone advised me to post the full version for clarity.

(Focus on the two functions `Update ()` and `DisableButtons()`.)

```
/* TappingEngine.cs */

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class TappingEngine : MonoBehaviour {


    public static TappingEngine te;
    public int nTaps = 0;
    public int GlobalTotal;
    public int RightTaps;
    public int LeftTaps;
    public string FirstTap;
    public int LastTap;
    public int MaxChain;
    public int FastestTwoTaps;
    public int FastestTwoChainedTaps;

    public GlobalTotalTaps GlobalTotalTaps_script;
    public TotalRightTaps RightTotalTaps_script;
    public TotalLeftTaps LeftTotalTaps_script;
    public FirstTap FirstTap_script;
    public RightButton RightButton_script;

    const float TimeSpan = 5F;
    public float Chrono;
    public bool ChronoStart = false;
    public bool ChronoFinished = false;
    public float ElapsedPercent = 0F;

    public enum tapType_t { right, left };

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GlobalTotal = 0;
        te = this;
        GlobalTotalTaps_script = FindObjectOfType(typeof(GlobalTotalTaps)) as GlobalTotalTaps;
        RightTotalTaps_script = FindObjectOfType(typeof(TotalRightTaps)) as TotalRightTaps;
        LeftTotalTaps_script = FindObjectOfType(typeof(TotalLeftTaps)) as TotalLeftTaps;
        FirstTap_script = FindObjectOfType(typeof(FirstTap)) as FirstTap;
        RightButton_script = FindObjectOfType(typeof(RightButton)) as RightButton;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(ChronoStart) {

            ElapsedPercent = (Time.time - Chrono) * 100 / TimeSpan;

            if(ElapsedPercent >= 100F) {
                DisableButtons();
                //SceneManager.LoadScene("Conclusion", LoadSceneMode.Single);
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Elapsed time: " + (Time.time - Chrono));
    }

    private void DisableButtons()
    {
        RightButton_script.DisableButton();
    }

    public void OnTap() {
        Debug.Log("Tap!");
    }

    public void Tap(tapType_t tapType) {

        Manage_GlobalTotalTaps();
        if(GlobalTotal == 1) {
            Manage_FirstTap(tapType);
            ChronoStart = true;
            Chrono = Time.time;
        }
        Manage_LeftRight(tapType);


    }

    private void Manage_FirstTap(tapType_t tapType)
    {
        FirstTap = tapType.ToString();
        FirstTap_script.FastUpdate();
    }

    private void Manage_LeftRight(tapType_t tapType)
    {
        if (tapType.Equals(tapType_t.left))
        {
            LeftTaps++;
            LeftTotalTaps_script.FastUpdate();
        }
        else
        {
            RightTaps++;
            RightTotalTaps_script.FastUpdate();
        }
    }

    public void Manage_GlobalTotalTaps() {
        GlobalTotal++;
        GlobalTotalTaps_script.FastUpdate();
    }
}
```

Below are a couple of screenshots that I hope will be useful.

[image]
[image]

Until now I have not yet figured out where the problem is.  Moreover, the script of the button is very similar to that of the various `Text` objects that represent the statistics (the list on the right side of the screen).

With `Text` objects it works, with the `Button` object not.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on Unity3D Forum and I got the solution [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/an-unity3d-button-appears-to-be-null-while-trying-to-disable-it.533629/#post-3513686).

One the game object where I attached the `RightButton.cs` there is a variable on line 24 `Button btn;` that needs to be set to `public`, so `public Button btn;`.

This makes appearing a new entry in the Inspector of the **Right Button** object (see the image below) and so in Unity3D drag and drop the **Right Button GameObject** into **Right Button (Script)**'s proper field (**Btn** in this case).

[image]